# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lauparse

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, linker, fedora, ld

How can I install the auparse library on Fedora 26?

```
$ gcc -lauparse me.c
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lauparse
```

I have tried many things, including these.

```
$ sudo find / -name *auparse.so
/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/auparse.so
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/
didnt help :{
sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/auparse.so /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/auparse.so
didnt help :{
$ pkg-config --libs auparse
Package auparse was not found in the pkg-config search path.
```

I'd really appreciate help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `audit-libs-devel`. Here's how I found that:

```
$ sudo dnf install /usr/lib64/libauparse.so
Dependencies resolved.
================================================================================
 Package               Arch        Version           Repository            Size
================================================================================
Installing:
 audit-libs-devel      x86_64      2.7.7-1.fc26      updates-testing       81 k
```

In general:

1. Libraries are gonna be in `/usr/lib64` on x86_64 systems.
2. `-lsomething` means to look for `/usr/lib64/libsomething.so`
3. And DNF has this neat feature where it can find things by file, so there you go.
4. Also, for most libraries on Fedora, there's a runtime package (here, `audit-libs` and then a devel package (`audit-libs-devel`) which contains the `.so` symlink and usually header files and stuff.